# Spring-boot @ExceptionHandler in Java8 is not reached out

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, exceptionhandler

I am using `@ExcpetionHandler` in my Java8 app. I'm unable to reach out to this function. Upon all exceptions, the HTTP response is always 500 (with the message I inserted into the exception), and it ignores the `@ExceptionHandler` methods.

When my colleague runs the app with java 7 compiler, it works.

Any reason why @ExceptionHandler annotation fails to be reached out with Java 8?

Controller:

`validateInput()` is throwing `InputParameterException`. `InputParameterException` is caught in the try/catch, which throws it again.

```
import org.apache.catalina.servlet4preview.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import vce.exception.InputParameterException;


@Controller
@RestController
public class VRestController {


    @Resource(name="aManager")
    AManager aManager;

    public void setAManager(AManager aManager) {
        this.aManager = aManager;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value ="/authentication/signature", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> signature(@RequestBody final Signature signature) {

        return handle(Marker.UseCases.SIGNATURE, new Supplier<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public Integer get() {
                validateInput(signature);
                aManager.doSomething(signature);
                return 0;
            }

        });
    }


    private ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handle(UseCases useCase, Supplier<Integer> supplier) {

        final Marker marker = Marker.REQUEST_MARKER.get();
        marker.startUseCase().setUseCase(useCase.name()).setStartTime(DateTime.now());
        try{
            marker.setSerializationId(serializationID);

            supplier.get();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            marker.setException(e);

            throw e;
        }

        finally {
          ......
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new ErrorResponse(200,0,"Success"));
    }


    private static void validateInput(Signature signature) {
        final String missingErr = "The request is missing the following parameter: ";

        if(signature.getData()==null) {
            throw new InputParameterException(missingErr+VConstants.DATA_FIELD_NAME, VErrorCodeEnum.MISSING_FIELD);
        }

        if(signature.getSignature()==null) {
            throw new InputParameterException(missingErr+VConstants.SIGNATURE_FIELD_NAME, VErrorCodeEnum.MISSING_FIELD);
        }
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(InputParameterException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorResponse handleInputParameterException(HttpServletRequest req, InputParameterException e) {
        .....
        return new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), e.getErrorCode().getCode(), e.getMessage());
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason="Internal Server Error - Any Exception")
    public void handleAnyException(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) {

        .....
    }

    static class ErrorResponse {

        public int statusCode;
        public int errorCode;
        public String message;

        public ErrorResponse(int statusCode, int errorCode, String message) {
            this.statusCode = statusCode;
            this.errorCode = errorCode;
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

Relevant part from pom.xml:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This code fails to reach out to `@ExceptionHandler` with Java8. When switching to Java7, without any code changes, it works.

**Update:**

The error message I receive is:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1494863566131,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "com.nds.ch.vge.vaus.exception.InputParameterException",
  "message": "org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.nds.ch.vge.vaus.exception.InputParameterException: The request is missing the following parameter: data",
  "path": "/authentication/signature"
}
```

I removed `@Controller` annotation and I also tried to use resolver, but it didn't work.

Code of the resolver, in the same package as the rest controller class:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@EnableWebMvc
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {


        @ExceptionHandler(InputParameterException.class)
        @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
        public ErrorResponse handleInputParameterException(HttpServletRequest req, InputParameterException e) {
            .....
            return new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), e.getErrorCode().getCode(), e.getMessage());
        }


        @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
        @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason="Internal Server Error - Any Exception")
        public void handleAnyException(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) {

            .....
        }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have both Controller and RestController? Have you tried putting the exceptionHandlers in its own Component class?

Comment: @Shervin Asgari, I want to have the ExceptionHandler inside the controller. I have only 1 controller and no need to use different class.

Comment: what is *the actual error* you see when you have 500?

Comment: The code looks correct, barring redundant `@Controller` and `@ResponeBody`. Perhaps the issue is at build stage? Try `mvn clean` before building with Java8.

Comment: @Eugene - yes, 500

Comment: @KerenSi that's an `error code` not an `error message`. What is the error from the logs that you get

Comment: @Eugene, I added the message into the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was importing the wrong `HttpServletRequest` class:

```
import org.apache.catalina.servlet4preview.http.HttpServletRequest;
```

The import should be:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
```

When I changed the import, the `@ExceptionHandler` methods worked.

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot to pick up your handler you have to put it in a separate class and annotate it properly.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@EnableWebMvc
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { NoHandlerFoundException.class })
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ApiErrorResponse noHandlerFoundException(Exception ex) {
        return new ApiErrorResponse(404, 4041, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Also I don't think it is a valid option to annotate your controller class with `@RestController` and `@Controller` as well. Choose one or another and annotate your exception handler class accordingly`(@RestControllerAdvice` or `@ControllerAdvice`)

Comment: I tried what you suggested - didn't work. I updated my post.

Comment: Please add this to your application.properties:                                         
`spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true`